# How to decide number of layers to add in a sequential model to solve a multiple linear regression problem using Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-regression, prediction, sequential

I was working on a problem defined in [Predict Fuel Efficiency](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_regression), in which I didn't get clarity that how one should decide the number of layers( hidden layers) to solve a multiple linear problem?

In the above defined problem, there are three hidden layers is being used.

ie.

```
myModel = keras.Sequential([
        layers.Dense(32, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape= [len(train_dataset.keys())]),
        layers.Dense(32, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        layers.Dense(1),
        ----   ])
```

For a similar problem, how I should decide the number of layers to add in the sequential model?

Comment: Read: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-to-choose-the-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-a-feedforward-neural-netw

Comment: unfortunately, there is no correct answer to this, it basically depends on the problem in my experience the only way is to experiment and start from the bottom and monitor the accuracy, more layers will not help in most of the cases